# Unable to boot Ubuntu on boot

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, grub

I have a dual boot system (Windows 8 and Ubuntu 16.04), I successfully install Ubuntu and then powered down and restarted my system, But on boot the Grub doesn’t load and it straight away boots to Windows.

How do I get the boot options back? Grub doesn’t show up on boot now.

Comment: Boot your live disc and run `boot-repair`. I can't remember if this is included in the live disc: you may need to install it on the live system, and you will need to do this each time you boot Ubuntu Live.

Comment: I installed Ubuntu Desktop using a USB, Can you help me detailed steps on how I could resolve my issue? I did read about boot-repair but no detailed step by step explanation :’(

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair > Use the 2nd Option in a Ubuntu live session, internet required. But if UEFI first check whether or not you can now select an Ubuntu entry in the firmware settings (hopefully you installed Ubuntu in UEFI mode).

Comment: Amplifying @MichaelBay's point, can you boot Ubuntu is you set your BIOS/UEFI into legacy mode?